# Как получить масив checkbox?

Tags: php, post

Я хочу добавить при отправке сообщения выбраные эти данные

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chec[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="chec[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="chec[]" value="3">
```

Но мне выдает ошибку, куда разместить этот foreach. что бы выводило сообщения нормально без синтаксической ошибки. Или может другой вариант вывода??

```
<?php

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
 if($post){

$mexpod = ($_POST['mexpod']);
foreach($mexpod as $mexanizmpod);

$punkt1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['punkt1']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
$error = '';
if(!$error) {

    $email = "ACS <test@com.com>\n\n"; 
    $address = "test@gmail.com"; 
    $sub = "Заявка ";
$mes = "
От - ".$punkt1."<br> 
// как правильно вставить сдесь foreach? 
foreach($mexpod as $item) echo "$item<br />"

<br>\n\nE-mail: ".$email."<br>\n\nСообщение: ".$message."<br>\n\n";

 $send = mail ($address,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/html; charset = UTF-8\r\nFrom:$email");
    if($send) {echo 'OK';}

if($mail)
{ echo 'OK';
}
  }else {echo '<div class="notification_error">'.$error.'</div>';}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял:

```
<?php

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
if ($post) {

    $mexpod = ($_POST['chec']);
    $punkt1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['punkt1']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
    $error = '';
    if (!$error) {

        $email = "ACS <test@com.com>\n\n";
        $address = "test@gmail.com";
        $sub = "Заявка ";
        $mes = "От - " . $punkt1 . "<br>";

        foreach ($mexpod as $item) {
            $mes .= "$item < br />";
        }
        $mes .= "<br>\n\nE-mail: " . $email . "<br>\n\nСообщение: " . $message . "<br>\n\n";

        $send = mail($address, $sub, $mes, "Content-type:text/html; charset = UTF-8\r\nFrom:$email");
        if ($send) {
            echo 'OK';
        }

        if ($mail) {
            echo 'OK';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<div class="notification_error">' . $error . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: а можно ли как то поместить под общий  $mes или это не возможно вообще?

Comment: или фореачь вынести а этот как то поместить в общий меседж $mes .= "$item < br />";

Comment: Если честно, не понятно, что вы хотите

Comment: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/916452/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-foreach-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-mes) вот посмотрите я новый запрос сделал