# Как foreach добавить в общий mes?

Tags: php

Я не могу понять в каком виде я могу объединить 
$mes и foreach

что я хочу

```
 $mes = "От - " . $punkt1 . "<br>"
              . foreach ($mexpod as $item) {
                $mes .= "$item < br />"
            }.
       "<br>\n\nE-mail: " . $email . "<br>\n\nСообщение: " . $message . "<br>\n\n";
```

А это то что имею. Возможно ли?

```
$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
if ($post) {

    $mexpod = ($_POST['chec']);
    $punkt1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['punkt1']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
    $error = '';
    if (!$error) {

        $email = "ACS <test@com.com>\n\n";
        $address = "test@gmail.com";
        $sub = "Заявка ";
        $mes = "От - " . $punkt1 . "<br>";

        foreach ($mexpod as $item) {
            $mes .= "$item < br />";
        }
        $mes .= "<br>\n\nE-mail: " . $email . "<br>\n\nСообщение: " . $message . "<br>\n\n";

        $send = mail($address, $sub, $mes, "Content-type:text/html; charset = UTF-8\r\nFrom:$email");
        if ($send) {
            echo 'OK';
        }

        if ($mail) {
            echo 'OK';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<div class="notification_error">' . $error . '</div>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если появляется ошибка **Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in**,  используя код @Nsk 
Добавляем array

```
$mes = "От - ". $punkt1 ."<br>".implode ('<br/>',(array)$mexpod)."<br>\n\nE-mail: ".$email." 
<br>\n\nСообщение: ".$message."<br>\n\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$mes = "От - ". $punkt1 ."<br>".implode ('<br/>',$mexpod)."<br>\n\nE-mail: ".$email." 
<br>\n\nСообщение: ".$message."<br>\n\n";
```